# In Parse, how can you remove someone from a role after requesting the resource X times?

Tags: parse-platform, roles

In my Parse app, I want Users to have access to an audio file only ten times.

Once they have listened to it 10 times, I don't want them to be able to access it.

Essentially, from my current understanding about Parse, I would have to somehow remove them from a role while keeping some kind of secure counter somewhere.

Is there a clean simple way to do this?

Comment: Are we talking about a few resources, or dozens/hundreds/thousands? I have a few ideas, but want to provide an optimal solution. I'm guessing a lot :)

Comment: There will be about 100 audio resources, and they can listen to each one 10 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on your comment about around 100 items, I think the easiest way to handle this is with something akin to a join table.**

Essentially, you will have a new Parse database class, call it 'Uses', that tracks how many uses of an item each user have. It will have the following fields:

- user (Pointer): The user in question
- resource (Pointer): The resource (audio file they have accessed)
- count (Number): The number of times they have used the resource

Your logic in the app should be as follows:

1. Query the Uses table for items where user = current user and resource = requested resource
2. If doesn't exist, create one and set the count = 1
3. If does exist, check the count
4. Count < 10? Play the item
5. Count > 10? Throw an alert

If security is paramount, you could do this via a [Cloud Code](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#cloud-code) call instead to prevent an unscrupulous (but very very smart) user from altering their entries in the Uses table. It depends on how paranoid you need to be.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Awesome thank you. I know you mentioned security, but don't I need an ACL here too to make each user can update his Uses entry?

Comment: Right you are. As a rule, you should ALWAYS be setting the ACL when adding/editing an object :)